# Insert Google Recaptcha inside Symfony2 Form

Tags: forms, symfony, recaptcha

I want to insert a div before my submit button.

```
->add('address',new AddressForm(array(
                ))
            ->add('Valider', 'submit', array(
                'attr' => array('class' => ' btn btn-lg btn-success btn-bloc')
            ))
            ->add('Cancel', 'reset', array(
                'attr' => array('class' => ' btn btn-lg btn-cancel btn-bloc')
    ))
```

This the div proposed by Google:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="***************************"></div>
```

I'm using Twig I did manage to add it after the Form but not inside it.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the EWZ bundle to add googles recapture to my forms

https://github.com/excelwebzone/EWZRecaptchaBundle

With that bundle you can just add "->add('recaptcha', 'ewz_recaptcha')" to your form builder, for example:

```
    $builder->add('name', 'text', array(
        'attr' => array(
            'placeholder' => 'Name',
            'pattern'     => '.{4,}' //minlength
        )
    ))
    ->add('email', 'email', array(
        'attr' => array(
            'placeholder' => 'Email'
        )
    ))
    ->add('company', 'text', array(
        'attr' => array(
            'placeholder' => 'Company/Organisation',
            'pattern'     => '.{3,}' //minlength
        )
    ))
    ->add('message', 'textarea', array(
        'attr' => array(
            'cols' => 90,
            'rows' => 10,
            'placeholder' => 'Leave a message...'
        )
    ))
    ->add('recaptcha', 'ewz_recaptcha')
    ->add('save', 'submit', array(
        'label' => 'Submit',
        'attr' => array (
            'class' => 'submit btn-block btn-lg btn-primary'
        )
    ));
```

Comment: thanks! that worked fine. I tried with the gemenuBundle but it didn't work, I like this bundle better and it's easy to configurate.